# how would I find all the places in all blueprints where there is a call to ParallelFor()?

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I'm trying to fix some incorrect calls to ParallelFor() that are appearing in performance profiles.  I can't seem to find it in the Blueprint scripts in the Unreal Engine 4 project I'm working with.  The Unreal documentation is sparse, and only tells me how to use it in C++.

Any ideas?  I'm really concerned that I can't do a plain-text search for functions like this inside the Blueprint scripts. The Unreal Engine dev forums didn't help.  The existing search mechanism via the search boxes appears to be for variables.

Using grep in the project folder fails.

Comment: [Agent Ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack/) seems to be able to find nodes by name. You can use it on your "Content" folder (not in the editor, but Windows Explorer) and search for "ParallelFor".

Comment: I tried Agent Ransack, but it didn't find them either.

Answer (score 1):

There are many factors to muti-threading speedup, number of cores, utilization, memory, scheduler...

The problem may be external to the code.

On to the question:

Many of the built-in blueprint functions are implemented natively in C++.

I would suggest looking at the profiler call stack(tree view); Follow it up to something named similar to a node.  This technique may fail for cross thread dispatches.

You will have to download the source code and look there to find the calls.

The other way is to build a debug build(with symbols) of the game and attach a debugger to the process.

Answer (score 0):

The call was built-in to the framework in my case.

Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily search trough all your BPs from withing the editor with
CTRL+SHIFT+F or window -> developer tools -> find in blueprints.
You get also there from within a blueprint, CTRL+F enter what you'r looking for, and on the right side there is kind of a book symbol in the same line where you can search all blueprints.

Comment: I tried that, it didn't work.